# Aligning gb4e examples in multicols

Tags: multicol, gb4e

For reasons of space I am trying to put pairs of correct and pairs of wrong examples next to each other in `multicols` environment. However, no matter what I do, they never align correctly. I tried `\bigskip` to fill the missing gloss line and even `\hspace` to create an empty line. I'll be very grateful for any suggestions where the problem lies and for any solutions. This is my first post, so I hope to get the MWE right.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\ex
\begin{xlist}
\ex \gll Dies ist korrekt\\
this is correct\\
\glt \lq This is correct'
\ex \gll \'{E}sto est\'{a} correcto\\
this is correct\\
\glt \lq This is correct'
\ex \gll Hii ni sahihi\\
this is correct\\
\glt \lq This is correct'
\end{xlist}
\columnbreak
\ex
\begin{xlist}
\ex[*]{\gll Dies falsch ist\\
this wrong is\\
\glt \hspace{1cm}}
\ex[*]{\gll \'{E}sto mal est\'{a}\\
this bad is\\
\glt \hspace{1cm}}
\ex[*]{ \gll Hii sahihi si\\
this correct not.is\\
\glt \hspace{1cm}}
\end{xlist}
\end{multicols}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the output]

Comment: Instead of the horizontal space you can put a phantom sentence: change `\glt \hspace{1cm}}` to `\glt \phantom{\lq This is correct'}}`.

Comment: @Marijn Can you turn your comment into an answer? Then we will have one less unanswered question on the site. :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the horizontal space you can put a phantom sentence: change `\glt \hspace{1cm}}` to `\glt \phantom{\lq This is correct'}}`. With `\phantom` the vertical and horizontal space of the argument is allocated, but it is not printed.

In the example:

```
\begin{xlist}
\ex[*]{\gll Dies falsch ist\\
this wrong is\\
\glt \phantom{\lq This is correct'}}
\ex[*]{\gll \'{E}sto mal est\'{a}\\
this bad is\\
\glt \phantom{\lq This is correct'}}
\ex[*]{ \gll Hii sahihi si\\
this correct not.is\\
\glt \phantom{\lq This is correct'}}
\end{xlist}
```

Result:

[image]